# Uniformly convergent sequence of functions in (0,1) that do no converges uniformly in [0,1]

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

Does there exist a uniformly convergent sequence of functions in (0,1) that does not converges uniformly on [0,1]?

Comment: Take the function $f_n(x) = n\mathbf{1}_{0}$. It is constant in $(0,1)$, therefore uniformly convergent, and it doesn't converge at the point $0$.

Comment: I suppose he means a sequence of function that is uniformly convergent on $]0,1[$ and pointwise convergent on $[0,1]$ but not uniformly convergent

Comment: One has to rephrase the question to make it meaningful: Is there a sequence of functions on $[0,1]$ which converges pointwise but not uniformly but whose restriction to the domain $(0,1)$ does converge uniformly on $(0,1)$? For pointwise convergence, this is easy, for example, $f_n(x) = \sum_1^n2^{-x}$ is pointwise convergent on $(0,1)$ but does not converge at $x=0$. But that $f(x)$ is not uniformly convergent on $(0,1)$. I suspected uniform convergence on an open interval implies uniform convergence on the closure of that interval, so the answer to your question is no. BUt that is untrue.

Comment: Thank you guys for the answers. But the question means exactly that.It's enough to the  sequence of functions not to be convergent at all for x=0 or x=1. I see now that this was a really silly question from my person.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, let 
$$f_n(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{cc}
(-1)^n, && x=0\text{ or }1\\
0, && x\in(0,1)\end{array}\right.$$

Answer (score 1):

Edit : the answer below is for another question than the one really asked (it was not clear at first):

> Let $f_n$ be a sequence of function that converge uniformly on $]0,1[$ and pointwise on $[0,1]$. Does it converge uniformly on $[0,1]$?.

And the answer is this question is yes :

Let $$a_n = \|f_n-f\|_{\infty, ]0,1[}$$ $$b_n = |f_n(0)-f(0)|$$ and $$c_n = |f_n(1)-f(1)|$$

Then

$$\|f_n-f\|_{\infty, [0,1]} = d_n = \max (a_n,b_n,c_n)$$

And as the three sequence converge to 0, the max of the three converge to 0

Comment: Are you assuming that $f$ is continuous?

Comment: Not at all. The trick is that if you add only a finite number of points to your domain, you keep the uniform convergence

Comment: This is flawed, since $f_n(0)$ hence $b_n$ need not be bounded. See  f_n(x) = \sum_1^n2^{-x}$ again.

Comment: I read the question as "let $f_n$ be a sequence of function that converge pointwise on [0,1] and uniformly on ]0,1[. Does it always converge uniformly on [0,1]?". But it seems I was mistaken